# Why do implict ODE solver from diffeqpy (Julia)always jump back to t=0?

Tags: python-3.x, julia, ode

I am using the diffeqpy package to use implicit solver from Julia in python in order to solve a DAE problem. While I was checking different values during the calculation, I noticed that the solver starts integrating from t=0 and eventually goes to the next time point t1>0, but jumps back to t=0 after a few iterations. After a while it jumps to the next time point t2>t1 and keeps going like this until t successfully reaches the specified end t=t<sub>end</sub>.

The solver I use is given below:

`dae_prob = de.DAEProblem(daefun,dy_dt_0,y0,tspan,differential_vars=differential_vars) sol = de.solve(dae_prob,de.DImplicitEuler(autodiff=False))`

Can anybody tell me why the solver always jumps back to t=0 (is it because of the implicit way of solving the DAE problem) and how does it effect the solution calculated by the solver if some parameters/variables depend on t ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. ODE/DAE solvers will often jump around in time (especially if you have callbacks that they need to find the time of when the callback happened). Specifically, I believe what you are obsreving is that the nonlinear solve that occurs in implicit methods generally has to evaluate the function a bunch of times at both the beginning and end of the step it is trying to take.

Lastly, you probably don't want to be using `DImplicitEuler`. For implicit DAEs, `DFBDF` or `IDA` (from `Sundials.jl`) will likely be faster. Furthermore, switching to the mass matrix formulation would let you use solvers like `Rosenbrock23` or `FBDF` thta will likely be faster still.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I actually changed to mass matrix formulation and I am currently using the Rosenbrock23. Is it generally more efficient to use ode solver with a mass matrix or are dae solver more suited ?

Comment: The mass matrix form is generally better (but you should benchmark as it does sometimes vary depending on your function.